# Create model loopback with type tsrange

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I am looking for a way to create a model in which there is a property with type tsrange in loopback 4 or is there a type that can replace tsrange ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the loopback datatype date and execute [plain SQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Executing-database-commands.html).

Example to check [overlap](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-range.html#RANGE-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) between 2 ranges:

```
SELECT  tsrange('2020-01-06 13:00', '2020-01-26 11:00', '[)')
    &&
        tsrange('2020-01-04 13:00', '2020-01-6 11:00', '[)')
```

tsrange() is used to construct the range, using [ and ) to set the boundaries. && is the operator that checks for an overlap between the 2 ranges.